# Autofill PDF file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, pdf

I have an app that allows users to sign a contract. The contract has 3 boxes that need to be autofilled with prices. The PDF will then need to be printed and emailed.

I already have created a view that allows for signature capture. It works by taking an CGImage of the view after the user signs (obviously there is more to it than that).

I can't seem to figure out 2 things:

1. How to autofill the boxes with prices
2. Embed the signature image with the PDF for printing.

Any help would be much appreciated and as always, thank you for your time.

---

Code to draw PDF file

```
if(document) {
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, currentPage);
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, [self bounds].size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);    
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to generate the rest of the PDF?

Comment: @sarnold I can add the entire class if it would help.

Comment: Hrm, I was under the assumption that you were generating the PDF on the fly, but this appears to be showing a static PDF. Are you creating PDFs on the fly or showing a single static one and hoping to modify the _image_ of the PDF once it is rendered?

Comment: I am reusing this code from a previous project that creates one on the fly, BUT I am only showing 2 PDFs in this project. To be honest, I'm not sure if I need to modify the image of the PDF once it is rendered.

Comment: You have probably figured it out by now, but if you are generating it on the fly, you should able to draw the signature image and the text for the prices like they do in this tutorial. http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/#more-242